# Reading from multiple TFRecord files

Tags: tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I am using multiple tfRecord files and want to read from them to create datasets. I am trying to use paths from_tensor_slices and use that dataset to further read TFRecords

(Advantages of multiple tfRecords : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16318/what-is-the-benefit-of-splitting-tfrecord-file-into-shards)

I want to know if there is an easier and proven method to do this.

```
file_names_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames_full)

def read(inp):
    return tf.data.TFRecordDataset(inp)

file_content = file_names.map(read)
```

My next step would be to parse the dataset using tf.io.parse_single_example for example.

Answer (score 5):

The [`tf.data.TFRecordDataset` constructor](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset#__init__) already accepts a list or a tensor of filenames. Hence, you can call it directly with your filenames: `file_content = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames_full)`

From the [`tf.io.parse_single_example` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/io/parse_single_example):

> One might see performance advantages by batching Example protos with parse_example instead of using this function directly.

Hence, I would recommend to batch your dataset before mapping the `tf.io.parse_example` function over it:

```
tf.data.TFRecordDataset(
  filenames_full
).batch(
  my_batch_size
).map(
  lambda batch: tf.io.parse_example(batch, my_features)
)
```

If you want a complete example, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58014123/11543584) I share my input pipeline (reading from many TFRecord files).

Kind, Alexis.