# How to improve data input pipeline performance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I try to optimize my data input pipeline.
The dataset is a set of 450 TFRecord files of size ~70MB each, hosted on GCS.
The job is executed with GCP ML Engine. There is no GPU.

Here is the pipeline:

```py
def build_dataset(file_pattern):
    return tf.data.Dataset.list_files(
        file_pattern
    ).interleave(
        tf.data.TFRecordDataset,
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    ).shuffle(
        buffer_size=2048
    ).batch(
        batch_size=2048,
        drop_remainder=True,
    ).cache(
    ).repeat(
    ).map(
        map_func=_parse_example_batch,
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    ).prefetch(
        buffer_size=1
    )
```

With the mapped function:

```py
def _bit_to_float(string_batch: tf.Tensor):
    return tf.reshape(tf.math.floormod(tf.dtypes.cast(tf.bitwise.right_shift(
        tf.expand_dims(tf.io.decode_raw(string_batch, tf.uint8), 2),
        tf.reshape(tf.dtypes.cast(tf.range(7, -1, -1), tf.uint8), (1, 1, 8))
    ), tf.float32), 2), (tf.shape(string_batch)[0], -1))


def _parse_example_batch(example_batch):
    preprocessed_sample_columns = {
        "features": tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        "booleanFeatures": tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, ""),
        "label": tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.float32, -1)
    }
    samples = tf.io.parse_example(example_batch, preprocessed_sample_columns)
    dense_float = tf.sparse.to_dense(samples["features"])
    bits_to_float = _bit_to_float(samples["booleanFeatures"])
    return (
        tf.concat([dense_float, bits_to_float], 1),
        tf.reshape(samples["label"], (-1, 1))
    )
```

I tried to follow the best practices of the [data pipeline tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets), and vectorize my mapped function (as advised by [mrry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53585477/11543584)).

With this settings, while data are downloaded at high-speed (bandwidth is around 200MB/s) the CPU is under-used (14%) and the training is very slow (more than 1hour for a epoch).

I tried some parameters configuration, changing the `interleave()` arguments like `num_parallel_calls` or `cycle_length` or the `TFRecordDataset` arguments like `num_parallel_calls`.

The fastest configuration uses this set of parameters:

- `interleave.num_parallel_calls`: 1
- `interleave.cycle_length`: 8
- `TFRecordDataset.num_parallel_calls`: 8

With this one, one epoch only take ~20 minutes to run. **However, CPU usage is only at 50% while bandwidth consumption is around 55MB/s**

### Questions:

1. How to optimize the pipeline to reach 100% CPU usage (and something like 100MB/s of bandwidth consumption)?
2. Why does `tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE` not find best value to speed up the training?

Kind,
Alexis.

---

### Edit

After some more experimentations, I came to the following solution.

1. Remove the `interleave` step which is already handled by `TFRecordDataset` if `num_parallel_calls` is greater than 0.
2. Update the mapped function to only do `parse_example` and `decode_raw`, returning a tuple `((, ), ())
3. `cache` after the `map`
4. Move the `_bit_to_float` function as a component of the model

Finally, here is the data pipeline code:

```py
def build_dataset(file_pattern):
    return tf.data.TFRecordDataset(
        tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern),
        num_parallel_reads=multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
        buffer_size=70*1000*1000
    ).shuffle(
        buffer_size=2048
    ).map(
        map_func=split,
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    ).batch(
        batch_size=2048,
        drop_remainder=True,
    ).cache(
    ).repeat(
    ).prefetch(
        buffer_size=32
    )


def split(example):
    preprocessed_sample_columns = {
        "features": tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        "booleanFeatures": tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, ""),
        "label": tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.float32, -1)
    }
    samples = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, preprocessed_sample_columns)
    dense_float = tf.sparse.to_dense(samples["features"])
    bits_to_float = tf.io.decode_raw(samples["booleanFeatures"], tf.uint8)
    return (
        (dense_float, bits_to_float),
        tf.reshape(samples["label"], (1,))
    )


def build_model(input_shape):
    feature = keras.Input(shape=(N,))
    bool_feature = keras.Input(shape=(M,), dtype="uint8")
    one_hot = dataset._bit_to_float(bool_feature)
    dense_input = tf.reshape(
        keras.backend.concatenate([feature, one_hot], 1),
        input_shape)
    output = actual_model(dense_input)

    model = keras.Model([feature, bool_feature], output)
    return model

def _bit_to_float(string_batch: tf.Tensor):
    return tf.dtypes.cast(tf.reshape(
        tf.bitwise.bitwise_and(
            tf.bitwise.right_shift(
                tf.expand_dims(string_batch, 2),
                tf.reshape(
                    tf.dtypes.cast(tf.range(7, -1, -1), tf.uint8),
                    (1, 1, 8)
                ),
            ),
            tf.constant(0x01, dtype=tf.uint8)
        ),
        (tf.shape(string_batch)[0], -1)
    ), tf.float32)
```

Thanks to all these optimizations:

- Bandwidth consumption is around 90MB/s
- CPU usage is around 20%
- First epoch spends 20 minutes
- Successives epochs spend 5 minutes each

So this seems to be a good first setup. But CPU and BW are still not overused, so any advice is still welcomed!

---

### Edit Bis

So, after some benchmarking I came accross what I think is our best input pipeline:

```
def build_dataset(file_pattern):
    tf.data.Dataset.list_files(
        file_pattern
    ).interleave(
        TFRecordDataset,
        cycle_length=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE,
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    ).shuffle(
        2048
    ).batch(
        batch_size=64,
        drop_remainder=True,
    ).map(
        map_func=parse_examples_batch,
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    ).cache(
    ).prefetch(
        tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    )

def parse_examples_batch(examples):
    preprocessed_sample_columns = {
        "features": tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature((), tf.float32, allow_missing=True),
        "booleanFeatures": tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, ""),
        "label": tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.float32, -1)
    }
    samples = tf.io.parse_example(examples, preprocessed_sample_columns)
    bits_to_float = tf.io.decode_raw(samples["booleanFeatures"], tf.uint8)
    return (
        (samples['features'], bits_to_float),
        tf.expand_dims(samples["label"], 1)
    )
```

So, what's new:

- According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31019#issuecomment-517044334), the `TFRecordDataset` interleaving is a legacy one, so `interleave` function is better.
- `batch` before `map` is a good habit ([vectorizing your function](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#batching)) and reduce the number of times the mapped function is called.
- No need of `repeat` anymore. Since TF2.0, the Keras model API supports the dataset API and can use cache (see the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58220646/11543584))
- Switch from a `VarLenFeature` to a `FixedLenSequenceFeature`, removing a useless call to `tf.sparse.to_dense`.

Hope this can help. Advices are still welcomed.

Comment: Thank you for not only asking the right question, but also for providing the answer with it. If I could, I would plus-two. :) EDIT: Actually, I just did sort of - I've upvoted your other answer that refers to this one. :)

Comment: @InnocentBystander You're welcome ^^ Thanks for the votes, they awarded me some badges too!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mentioning the Solution and the Important observations of @AlexisBRENON in the Answer Section, for the benefit of the Community.

Below mentioned are the Important Observations:

1. According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31019#issuecomment-517044334), the `TFRecordDataset` `interleaving` is a legacy one, so `interleave` function is better.
2. `batch` before `map` is a good habit ([vectorizing your function](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#batching)) and reduce the number of times the mapped function is called.
3. No need of `repeat` anymore. Since TF2.0, the Keras model API supports the dataset API and can use cache (see the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57977408/how-to-cache-and-iterate-through-a-dataset-of-unknown-size/58220646#58220646))
4. Switch from a `VarLenFeature` to a `FixedLenSequenceFeature`, removing a useless call to `tf.sparse.to_dense`.

Code for the Pipeline, with improved performance, in line with above observations is mentioned below:

```
def build_dataset(file_pattern):
    tf.data.Dataset.list_files(
        file_pattern
    ).interleave(
        TFRecordDataset,
        cycle_length=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE,
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    ).shuffle(
        2048
    ).batch(
        batch_size=64,
        drop_remainder=True,
    ).map(
        map_func=parse_examples_batch,
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    ).cache(
    ).prefetch(
        tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    )

def parse_examples_batch(examples):
    preprocessed_sample_columns = {
        "features": tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature((), tf.float32, allow_missing=True),
        "booleanFeatures": tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, ""),
        "label": tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.float32, -1)
    }
    samples = tf.io.parse_example(examples, preprocessed_sample_columns)
    bits_to_float = tf.io.decode_raw(samples["booleanFeatures"], tf.uint8)
    return (
        (samples['features'], bits_to_float),
        tf.expand_dims(samples["label"], 1)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a further suggestion to add:

According to the documentation of [interleave()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave), you can as the first parameter
use a mapping function.

This means, one can write:

```py
 dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern)
 dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x:
    tf.data.TFRecordDataset(x).map(parse_fn, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE),
    cycle_length=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE,
    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
    )
```

As I understand it, this maps a parsing function to each shard, and then interleaves the results. This then eliminates the use of `dataset.map(...)` later on.

Comment: I did not experiment a lot lastly. But I don't think that your solution brings much improvements. I think that `interleave` take care of IO blocking behavior (not requiring CPU) while `map` is most of the time CPU intensive (so it cannot be parallelized a lot).
So, I think your solution is roughly equivalent to `interleave().map()`.
To make sure, feel free to experiment with [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#reproducing_the_figures), or [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance).